# Managing android's backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity hierarchy and I have a button that allows me to go from activity D to activity B.

[image]

The thing is that going to B from D would leave C on the backstack, so if I do A->C->D->B and then press back it would send me to C, and not to A (which is what I want).

Is there a way to delete C when I click on the button from B, or is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: You could do it with Fragments instead, FragmentManager lets you manage the stack. Also look up parent activities: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `A` as a dispatcher. When you want to launch `B` from `D` and finish `C` in the process, do this in `D`:

```
// Launch A (our dispatcher)
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
// Setting CLEAR_TOP ensures that all other activities on top of A will be finished
//  and setting SINGLE_TOP ensures that a new instance of A will not
//  be created (the existing instance will be reused and onNewIntent() will be called)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
// Add an extra telling A that it should launch B
intent.putExtra("startB", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

in `A.onNewIntent()` do this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra("startB")) {
        // Need to start B from here
        startActivity(new Intent(this, B.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked just fine. How does this method work efficiency-wise? Does it run activity A all the way up to onResume() before running the intent?

Comment: Probably. I don't remember exactly whether it calls `onResume()` in this case, since another Activity will be started. It may. You can add some logging to see for yourself. I don't think this is an efficiency issue to worry about though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of how you're calling B, C and D or what data is getting passed around, but you can close C when you call D if you want.

In C, when starting D, you could do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, D.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The finish will close C after starting D.

Again, without much info this is just a shot in the dark though.

Comment: A, B and C can be called from any other activity through a button bar, whereas D can only be called from C.
I dont want to finish C as I open D because pressing the back button would make me go over to A.

Comment: The this approach won't work. If you want to go from D to B, then you may need to use fragments with a fragment manager, or create your own stack manager.